# How to determine if mousepointer is over an element that should trigger onMouseOver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash

I am attempting to mimic the bing video search preview feature. I have a single flash video player element which loads on page load. I also have multiple images contained in overlay divs that should trigger playback (onMouseOver event in the div), and move the flash player into the div position.

I have two problems related to where the mouse pointer is located:

- When the `onMouseOver` event is triggered, I do a `$(element).css("visibility","hidden");` on the `<img />`, and move the flash player into the exact same position. This works okay, except that the `onMouseOut` event is triggered immediately followed by the `onMouseOver` event once again causing the video to 'flicker' as it reloads the video. How can I make sure the incorrectly fired `onMouseOut` event is indeed incorrect (and not stop/start video playback)?
- If the mousepointer is over a div with the preview image on page load (before the flash player is loaded), the `onMouseOver` event is never triggered for this element - how can I do this? When the flash is loaded, it triggers a callback - but I don't really know how I can accurately mimic the `onMouseOver` event? This is less of an issue than the other problem, but would be cool if it's possible to fix

Comment: Could you post a sample of the html/javascript.  Which `mouseout` is fired?  That of the image, that of the video or of some parent of one or both?

Comment: $('element').hover(function(){ MOUSE IN }, function(){ MOUSE OUT });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead.
2. Reinitialize the function for mouseenter when the flash is loaded.